# Uniqueness in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm sure there is an answer to this somewhere else, but I'm simply not sure how to find it or what to call it. I looked online, but couldn't find anything.

The question is as follows:

Let $A$ and $C$ be $n \times n$ matrices.

If $AB = C$, where $A$ and $C$ are fixed, is $B$ necessarily unique?

Obviously $B$ is $n \times n$, but I'm not sure whether it could vary. It seems like it should be unique but I can't think how I would prove it.

**EDIT**

I should mention neither A or C are the 0 matrix. If A was the 0 matrix obviously B could be anything. Note sure what happens when C = 0, but it doesn't apply to the cases I'm considering.

Comment: @Cocopuffs thanks for pointing that out, it should have been something that was obvious that I should mention that I'm thinking about non-zero matrices. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then $B=A^{-1}C$, so $B$ is unique. Otherwise, $B$ can certainly fail to be unique.

For example, let $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$ and let $C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$. Then $B$ can be any matrix of the form $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}* & * \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$, where the $*$ entries are free to take any value.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly there will be cases where, for some matrix $A$ and vector $b$, the equation $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions in vectors $x$.

Now let $C$ be the matrix where each column is $b$.